# At the beginning of episode 10, why is Yumoto so happy he got a cold for the first time in his life?

Tags: boueibu

The theme of episode 10 of *Binan Koukou Chikyuu Boueibu Love* is Yumoto catching a cold for his first time.

When his cold is confirmed, he is exhilarating that it is the first cold in his life.

Why is he so happy?

Comment: can somebody make a tag excerpt for this tag?

Comment: In Japan, it is said that idiots don't get colds (one of the guys mentions this at some point in the episode). Perhaps Yumoto was thrilled because getting a cold proves that he isn't an idiot.

Comment: @Hakase I'll do it after dinner if nobody did already.